# How do i split string into a List, but there are different symbols to be split by

Tags: c#

This is the string i want to split: `"Pesho=11;Gosho=4"`. I want this string to be 4 separate elements in a List:`Pesho` , `11`, `Gosho`, `4`. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do a `Split()` on it, should solve your issue like so:

```
var results = "Pesho=11;Gosho=4".Split('=', ';');
```

Comment: it outputs a list of strings, so if you were to do `string[] results = "Pesho=11;Gosho=4".Split('=', ';');` the result should be the same.
As a sidenote, adding the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as an extra option, as pointed out by @JonasH is a good thing to do as well, as, while not relevant in your specific case, it filters out empty cases such as if your string was `";Pesho=11;Gosho=4"`, where you would get a 5th result with values `string.Empty`, which you would otherwise have to filter away by hand

Answer (score 4):

[String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-string()-system-stringsplitoptions)) has overloads that takes an array of separators:

```
var result = "Pesho=11;Gosho=4".Split(new []{'=', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```